# Iterative Query for Spatial Records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created following query in SQL Server

```
declare @x XML
set @x='<Dataset_Extent>
      <EXTENT_TYPE>Bounding_Polygon</EXTENT_TYPE>
      <Vertex>
        <LON>66.91292909247741</LON>
        <LAT>30.27001012181008</LAT>
        <X>299232</X>
        <Y>3350549</Y>
        <COL>1</COL>
        <ROW>1</ROW>
      </Vertex>
      <Vertex>
        <LON>66.99456841960638</LON>
        <LAT>30.27128639618252</LAT>
        <X>307089.5</X>
        <Y>3350549</Y>
        <COL>15715</COL>
        <ROW>1</ROW>
      </Vertex>
      <Vertex>
        <LON>66.99700791329992</LON>
        <LAT>30.1509623521339</LAT>
        <X>307089.5</X>
        <Y>3337207.5</Y>
        <COL>15715</COL>
        <ROW>26683</ROW>
      </Vertex>
      <Vertex>
        <LON>66.91546772378466</LON>
        <LAT>30.14969219541345</LAT>
        <X>299232</X>
        <Y>3337207.5</Y>
        <COL>1</COL>
        <ROW>26683</ROW>
      </Vertex>
      <Center>
        <LON>66.9549932872921</LON>
        <LAT>30.21048776638499</LAT>
        <X>303160.75</X>
        <Y>3343878.25</Y>
        <COL>7858</COL>
        <ROW>13342</ROW>
      </Center>
    </Dataset_Extent>';
declare @wkt varchar(8000);
select @wkt=CONVERT(varchar(7000),@x.query('distinct-values(
for $lon in /Dataset_Extent/Vertex/LON/text()
for $lat in /Dataset_Extent/Vertex/LAT/text()
return ($lon cast as xs:string?,$lat cast as xs:string?,","))
'));

--concatenate the word POLYGON
set @wkt='POLYGON(('+@wkt +'))';
print @wkt
```

This gives me the following output:

```
POLYGON((66.91292909247741 66.99456841960638 30.27128639618252 66.99700791329992 66.91546772378466 30.27001012181008,30.1509623521339 30.14969219541345))
```

Each Lon/lat pair is not in proper order, I required output in following format:

```
POLYGON((66.91292909247741 30.27001012181008,66.99456841960638 30.27128639618252,66.99700791329992 30.1509623521339,66.91546772378466 30.14969219541345,66.91292909247741 30.27001012181008))
```

The starting vertex Lon/Lat should also repeat at end to make polygon close.

What do I need to do this to fix the problems?

Answer (score 1):

this will do the job...

```
DECLARE @wkt NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @wkt = COALESCE(@wkt + ',' + char(13), '') 
+ concat(convert(varchar, x.query('./LON/text()')),' ', convert(varchar,x.query('./LAT/text()')))
from @x.nodes('/Dataset_Extent/Vertex') as t(x)

select @wkt = COALESCE(@wkt + ',' + char(13), '') 
+ concat(convert(varchar, x.query('./LON/text()')),' ', convert(varchar,x.query('./LAT/text()')))
from @x.nodes('/Dataset_Extent/Vertex[1]') as t(x)

set @wkt='POLYGON(('+@wkt +'))';
print @wkt
```

not exactly beautiful but i couldnt figure out how to subquery the first node... good luck!  i try to avoid xpath as much as possible if i can :)

Answer (score 1):

Shred the XML on `/Dataset_Extent/Vertex` and build the string using the `for xml path` trick.

```
declare @wkt varchar(8000);

set @wkt = 'POLYGON((' +
           stuff((select ','+T.X.value('(LON/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')+
                         ' '+T.X.value('(LAT/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')
                  from @x.nodes('/Dataset_Extent/Vertex') as T(X)
                  for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')+
           ','+@x.value('(/Dataset_Extent/Vertex/LON/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')+
           ' '+@x.value('(/Dataset_Extent/Vertex/LAT/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')+
           '))';
```

Against a table it would look like this instead.

```
select  'POLYGON((' +
        stuff((select ','+T.X.value('(LON/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')+
                      ' '+T.X.value('(LAT/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')
               from X.XMLData.nodes('/Dataset_Extent/Vertex') as T(X)
               for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')+
        ','+X.XMLData.value('(/Dataset_Extent/Vertex/LON/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')+
        ' '+X.XMLData.value('(/Dataset_Extent/Vertex/LAT/text())[1]', 'varchar(50)')+
        '))'
from XMLFiles as X;
```

Comment: Thats nice. It giving me all POLYGONS in my table in format          POLYGON((LON LAT, LON LAT,LON LAT,LON LAT)). It round about 300 rows and may be increase in future as data inserted. Now I want to apply STIntersects() function on each of the result row against my provided polygon e.g. POLYGON((66.9214310204
30.1191654521,66.9724466643 30.1273507980,66.9612156084 30.1614246796,66.9324717194 30.1540007613,66.9214310204 30.1191654521)), to check whether it intersects with any of them or not. I have to return all records whoes STIntersects() results would be =1. Thanks